# <p:graphicImage src not found 404

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to read some images inserted in my project but I can't do it.
I created a maven Dynamic Web Module 3.0 project and in the web content I inserted the resources / images folder. I added the folder in the build path because I thought it wasn't reachable but it doesn't work.

I have tried different code modes:

```
<p:graphicImage value="resources/images/chardonnay.png"/>
<p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images/muller.png']} />
<p:graphicImage value="#{resources['images:muller.png']} />
<p:graphicImage library="images" name="riesiling.png"/>
```

This is the structure of my project

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>safetyfood</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet- 
class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>    

</web-app>
```

And this is a pom.xml

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF- 
8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<!-- Prime faces dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- jsf maven dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

errors in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/safetyfood/resources/images/chardonnay.png? 
pfdrid_c=true 404
(index):25 GET http://localhost:8080/safetyfood/RES_NOT_FOUND 
404
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: This is needed since you did not put the resources in the defaiult location in the first place which is a subfolder of the 'webapp' folder which is in your case 'webContent' which in turn is the default for eclipse but not maven where you most likely also need to configure this. So you have lots of configuration things due to not using defaults.